Why is the hatching of dots inside the polygon not displayed on the geoserver?
I have this style in sld format:
<se:PolygonSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/pixel">
    <se:Fill>
      <se:GraphicFill>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#03f843</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">1</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#03f843</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">1</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
            <se:WellKnownName>shape://dot</se:WellKnownName>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>25</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:GraphicFill>
      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#efefef</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">1</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Fill>
    <se:Stroke>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
    </se:Stroke>
  </se:PolygonSymbolizer>

In a polygon created using this style, the points inside are not displayed. If I change shape://dot to any other (for example shape://plus), then everything is displayed correctly inside the polygon. What's wrong with the dots? Why are they not displayed?
Logs:
[renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://dot
TRACE  [renderer.style] - Could not find the symbol, returning null
TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://dot
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying fill to mark
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying stroke to mark
TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://dot
TRACE  [renderer.style] - Could not find the symbol, returning null
TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://dot
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying fill to mark
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying stroke to mark

But the exact same thing is displayed for other characters (for example shape://vertline).
TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://vertline
TRACE  [renderer.style] - Could not find the symbol, returning null
TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name shape://vertline
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying fill to mark
TRACE  [renderer.style] - applying stroke to mark

But shape://vertline is displayed correctly.
